# In tkinter, unable put label to the left, It remains in the middle

Tags: python, tkinter

I mean i am reading a txt file, For every line in txt file i
want a new label.

```
root = tk.Tk()

#here it opens the file
with open("/file.txt", "r") as openedFile:

    allLines = openedFile.readlines()
    for line in allLines:
        textInLine = line

        testText = Label(root, text=textInLine)
        testText.pack()

root.geometry("400x300")
root.mainloop()
```

Here in the text file lengths of lines is not same, so it puts the label text horizontally centered, i want it sticking to the left most side.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `anchor` attribute:

```
testText.pack(anchor="w")
```

`w` means 'west'

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways how you can manage your widgets.

First one is by `packing` like:

```
testText = Label(root, text="Test Text")
testText.pack(anchor=W)
```

Second one would be by `placing` (absolute positioning):

```
testText2 = Label(root, text="Test Text 2")
testText2.place(x=0, y=50, anchor=W)
```

And the third one would be `grids`.

Its a bit more complicated but probably the best one for managing widgets by position and dynamicaly to the window geometry. More about `grids` you can read [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/)